# Feed Elastic from Relational Database?

Tags: elastic-stack

I know this has been asked before, but most answers are from years ago.

Can anyone advise on recent ELK best practices for feeding data from a relational database into Elastic?  I understand about denormalization.  And I know I could write my own Java job to select from database with a JOIN, and then pass that.  I also know there is a JDBC plugin for LogStash, but we're using FileBeat.  At the moment, we have no need for near-real-time synchronicity.  An hourly batch job would be fine.

So, could anyone advise in general?  Or point me to links that might help?  Should I just write this myself (not hard), or is there a more convenient way now?

Thanks!

Comment: For anyone interested, I found an excellent discussion of my question here:  https://discuss.elastic.co/t/sync-elasticsearch-with-mysql-database/234032  Which includes a link to a good tutorial, here:  https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-to-keep-elasticsearch-synchronized-with-a-relational-database-using-logstash